# open query on oracle link server returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

im executing this opequery

```
SELECT * FROM openquery([GYM_DB],
      'SELECT 
   ROW_INDEX
      ,Jk_LR
      ,Jk_LR_
      ,Y_DATE
      ,WCODE
      ,T_RY
      ,WINNER
      ,WIN_TIME
      ,WIN_DATE
      ,JJT
      ,HOME
      ,FAMILY
      ,STORE_E46
      ,KAY_LQ
      ,GA_STATUS
  FROM GYM.G_TEST_Q4 
  where Y_DATE=20210518
  ')
```

and return this error:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "GYM_DB" returned message "ORA-00911: invalid character".
> which special character causes this error?

Comment: Why does the question have the SQL Server tag?   You should be clear in the question that you are running this on SQL Server and the linked server is Oracle.

Comment: @gordonlinoff cause my database is ms sql server.

Comment: `Y_DATE=20210518` This looks highly suspicious. What is the datatype of Y_DATE? Do you understand that the sql dialect used by oracle can be very, VERY different from that of SQL Server?

Comment: @SMor i removed Y_DATE where clause and still getting same error.

Comment: First write a query that works using the Oracle tools. When/if that works. then try the same query using openquery. Comment out all the columns in the select list except the first. Run the query. Does it work? If so, uncomment another column. Repeat. This is basic debugging.

Comment: @SMor thanks for your solution. i removed spaces and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

i received this query and executed and received that error.
I deleted all of the spaces and again i added enters between query lines and now it works.
i think there was tab or something in that spaces.